# how to perform group by rolling efficiently based on datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas

let's firstly create a medium size random df:

```
size_now = 1e5

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now)),
             "id":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now)),
             "data":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now))})

df.time =  pd.to_datetime(df.time,unit="s")
```

df looks like this:

```
print(df)
executed in 9ms, finished 15:16:05 2021-07-19
                     time   id  data
0     1970-01-01 00:15:01  915   299
1     1970-01-01 00:08:30   31   940
2     1970-01-01 00:02:55  925   600
3     1970-01-01 00:12:48  554   935
4     1970-01-01 00:07:43  565   638
...                   ...  ...   ...
99995 1970-01-01 00:16:27  707   615
99996 1970-01-01 00:01:06  298    38
99997 1970-01-01 00:14:26   37    43
99998 1970-01-01 00:16:09   66   791
99999 1970-01-01 00:01:45  376   854
```

I realized rolling sum can be pretty fast:

```
df.set_index("time").sort_index().rolling("2500ms")["data"].sum()

time
1970-01-01 00:00:00        66.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00       809.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00       879.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00      1329.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00      1729.0
                         ...   
1970-01-01 00:16:39    124998.0
1970-01-01 00:16:39    125265.0
1970-01-01 00:16:39    126050.0
1970-01-01 00:16:39    126782.0
1970-01-01 00:16:39    127766.0
Name: data, Length: 100000, dtype: float64
```

It only took 0.031s to complete the task. However, what I need is group by id and perform rolling on time. So here is my goal:

```
df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms",on="time")["data"].sum()

id   time               
0    1970-01-01 00:05:43      161.0
     1970-01-01 00:12:05      288.0
     1970-01-01 00:00:35      981.0
     1970-01-01 00:00:22      479.0
     1970-01-01 00:09:33      834.0
                             ...   
999  1970-01-01 00:15:07    28159.0
     1970-01-01 00:06:39    29035.0
     1970-01-01 00:06:15    29538.0
     1970-01-01 00:09:07    29788.0
     1970-01-01 00:00:48    30736.0
Name: data, Length: 100000, dtype: float64
```

But it took 2s to complete the task. I wanted to know if there is much more efficient to do this.

I thought presorting may be helpful, so I tried:

```
df = df.set_index(["id","time"]).sort_index()
```

This is very fast too. After this, we just need to cut our dataframe into multiple small frame and do rolling sum and concat them together... so I tried

```
df.groupby(level=0).rolling("2500ms")
```

but it gives me this error

> ValueError: window must be an integer

so i tried:

```
df.groupby(level=0).rolling("2500ms",on=df.index.levels[1]).sum()
```

this breaks my Jupiter notebook, giving me kernel dead error.

So I tried

```
df_tmp_list = []

for j in df.index.unique(level=0):
    df_tmp = df.loc[j]
    df_tmp = df_tmp.rolling("2500ms").sum()
    df_tmp["id"] = j
    df_tmp_list.append(df_tmp)
#     break

pd.concat(df_tmp_list).reset_index().set_index(["id","time"])
```

This also took 2.6s... What would be the most efficient way for me to achieve?

```
df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms",on="time")["data"].sum()
```

**Edit**
Thanks everyone for answering. It seems everyone runs it much faster than I do. I need 2s, others need 50ms... to be exactly clear, the complete code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size_now = 1e5

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now)),
             "id":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now)),
             "data":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now))})

df.time =  pd.to_datetime(df.time,unit="s")

%time df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms",on="time")["data"].sum()
```

my output is

```
CPU times: user 2.3 s, sys: 24 ms, total: 2.32 s
Wall time: 2.32 s
```

I am actually running on AWS-EC2 with 4 cpus and 16GB RAM.I have tried to update packages:

```
  510  conda update pandas
  511  conda update numpy
```

so speed didn't get improved... Any help?I'm very frustrated...

I tried on my MacBook Pro, with 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 and 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. It took 450ms... still much slower than all of you guys.... Please help me...

**Edit2**, so it is due to some mysterious installation issue. I have to update anaconda with latest download.

```
  523  curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
  525  bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh -u
```

Now it runs with 50ms. problem solved!

Comment: It takes you two seconds to complete on this sample frame . . . `38.9 ms ± 6.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris, Thanks! my point is that df.set_index("time").sort_index().rolling("2500ms")["data"].sum()
can be done in 31ms. So theoretically thinking, after pre-sorting, df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms",on="time")["data"].sum()
shall also be done very fast.... didn't expect it to take 2s....

Comment: `df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms",on="time")["data"].sum()` ran in 38 ms when I ran it with just 16gb of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can gain anything:

```
>>> %timeit df.set_index('time').groupby('id').rolling('2500ms').sum()
57.9 ms ± 1.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms", on="time")["data"].sum()
33.9 ms ± 466 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It is very weird.... it took me this long : 1.87 s ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Don't use Jupyter Notebook... Try with IPython console.

Comment: I have 38.1 ms ± 4.27 ms per loop on MBP 2018 in Jupyter Notebook.

Groupby can take time especially for large datasets. Index and sort on the Id columns before the groupby is propably the most efficient as @Corralien demonstrated above.

Comment: so i used ipython: In [6]: %timeit df.groupby("id").rolling("2500ms", on="time")["data"].sum()

1.78 s ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2**, so it is due to some mysterious installation issue. I have to update anaconda with latest download.

```
  523  curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
  525  bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh -u
```

Now it runs with 50ms. problem solved!